# Different Query Result in SQL Server 2005

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server 2005, and it has column `period (datetime)`.

The value of the column period is `8/7/2009 12:00:00 AM`, when I query using php script it give me output `Aug 7 2009 12:00AM`.

Why it's not `8/7/2009 12:00:00 AM` ???

Thank you

Comment: They look the same to me.  Do you not like the way the PHP script formats `DateTime` values?

Comment: Yes I Do. However, I don't have choice to reformatting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question reads like this:

> The value of the column period is
>   `{ a date, year 2009 month August day 7th at 12:00 AM}`
>   When I query using php script it give me output `"Aug 7 2009 12:00AM"`, i.e. one representation of the date.
>   Why it's not `"8/7/2009 12:00:00 AM"`, i.e. another representation of the date

A datetime represents a point in time.  It is a specific concept.  You are comparing two separate ***representations*** of the datetime, or in other words, two ways of formatting the datetime value as a textual string.

The issue you are trying to solve is then, **"How do I format a datetime as a string in PHP"?**  For which the answer would be to refer to the [date_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) (aka `DateTime::format`) function

To wit, the display specifier for `8/7/2009 12:00:00 AM` is **`n/j/Y h:i:s A`**.

Comment: I just wondering why it doesn't give me "what I see is what I get" without formatting the result query. lol...
Thank Richard